# Does Jface data-binding support this

Tags: java, eclipse, data-binding, swt, jface

I have something like this

```
public class Foo{
 private Bar bar; 
}

public class Bar{
 private String property;
}
```

I want to add binding to the field `property`, the problem is that the field `bar` in my object `Foo` changes on selection. So either I do my binding on Bar and each time it changes I remove the binding and recreate it or do something like

```
BeanProperties.value(Foo.class, "bar.property").observe(realm, foo);
```

is this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short answer :yes indeed data-binding supports this.